# Transforming a variable name as a string in react and trying to change its numeric value in React

Tags: reactjs

Hello I have a function on React activated by a click that gets an attribute of the button to try to affect a variable with the same name and add 1 to it and be usable elsewhere.
I know this is not the kosher way to do it in react, but since my knowledge of the language is limited an my time reduced, I was trying to find something that doesn't force me to change the whole page (and even so I wouldn't know how to do it).

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
//check the original value of the var I'm trying to change in this test (with this working I won't know which button I'm clicking on)
console.log(myVar);

//get the name of the variable based on the button clicked
const name = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value")

//check the value of the variable
console.log(eval(name));

//Add +1 to that variable - I've tried global(), window()... didn't work
name=name+1;

//check the var I'm using for the test to check if it has changed
console.log(myVar);

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For more clarity, the result of those console.log are: 4, nameofthevar, 4, 4 (trying this last one to become 5)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this

```
const handleClick = (e) => {

//get the string with the name of the var
const name = e.currentTarget.getAttribute("data-value")

//convert the numeric value of that var and add 1
const numberVal = parseInt(eval(name))+1;

//use eval to change the original variable
eval(name + " = " + numberVal)

}
```